# Output stops after a while loop, without using "or die()"

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I know there is another question with the same topic, but that question involves the or die() statement. I have the same problem, but i'm not using a or die() statement on my while loop. The answer is probably pretty obvious, but i can't figure it out.

```
$Dates = "1";
$Select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ----");
while ($Dates != "") {
$Dates = $Select->fetch_assoc();
$Get = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM " . $Dates["Meeting_Date"] . " WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'");
$Vals = $Get->fetch_assoc();
if ($Vals != "") {
$TimeIn = $Vals["Time_In"];
$TimeIn2 = explode(":",$TimeIn);
$TotIn = ($TimeIn2[0]*60)+$TimeIn2[1];
$TimeOut = $Vals["Time_Out"];
$TimeOut2 = explode(":",$TimeOut);
$TotOut = ($TimeOut2[0]*60)+$TimeOut2[1];
$TotTime = ($TotOut - $TotIn)/60;
$TotalTime = floor($TotTime) . " Hours " . ($TotTime-floor($TotTime))*60 . " Minutes";
echo "<tr><td>" . str_replace("_","/",$Dates["Meeting_Date"]) . "</td><td>" . $TimeIn . "</td><td>" . $TimeOut . "</td><td>" . $TotalTime . "</td></tr>";
}
if ($Vals == "") {
echo "<tr><td>" . str_replace("_","/",$Dates["Meeting_Date"]) . "</td><td colspan='3' style='background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25)'>Did not Attend</td></tr>";
}
}
```

Anything i put after the while loop, doesn't get executed, even though the while loop only executes 2 times like it is supposed to...

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: try turning on error reporting or check your error log. Nothing stands out as syntactically bad.

Comment: that's a horrid while construct. why not simply `while($Vals = $Get->fetch_assoc())`? it'll automatically terminate itself when there are no rows left, or no rows to begin wtih.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
while ($Dates != "") {
  $Dates = $Select->fetch_assoc();
  $Get = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM " . $Dates["Meeting_Date"] . " WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'");
```

When there are no more records, `$Dates` will be empty (`NULL`) so the next line will lead to a fatal error.

You can change it to:

```
while ($Dates = $Select->fetch_assoc()) {
  $Get = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM " . $Dates["Meeting_Date"] . " WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'");
```

Comment: @Ryan Andrews You're welcome. By the way, do you really need one table per date, that sounds unnecessary?

Comment: Well, technically, before the loop it write the headers, then it just writes table rows in the loop, then after the loop it closes the table.